# Некто иной / не кто иной (без "как")

Tags: орфография

Можете сказать, сохраняется ли раздельной написание, если в данном случае нет слова *как*?

Примеры: *Я не думаю, что это был Георг. Это, наверное, был **нéкто** другой; По-её, это сделал не Федя, а **нéкто** иной; Нет, сэр, нет, боже упаси! Конечно же-с у нас не было пожара! Случилось, однако, **нéчто** иное, более ужасное.*

Comment: Тыквинич, как обычно: лучше уж тогда по-ея - хотя, эта форма не встречается, но я почти уверен что должна быть именно она. По-его, по-моему, по-ея. Некто, нечто - слитно, указание на кого-то, что-то. Не кто - отрицание кого-то: "не кто, а что", аналогично "не что, а кто". А бывает еще нешто(по произношению) - это значит совсем другое, не такое как иное, не что-то иное, а совершенно из другой оперы. Но можно "не кто, а иной кто-то/(или даже)иное что-то/иные" или даже "не кто-то, а иной", с таким противопоставление. Меня встретился не кто-то из командования, а иной человек.

Comment: Тыквиныч, почему ты никогда не комментируешь свои вопросы?